# Fast direct way to create array for training labels to feed to Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, training-data

Let's say I want to train a simple model in keras, on a dataset that contains, for simplicity,

- 3 labels
- 10 dim, for 6 observations.

Note that I am simplifying for the purpose of this example.

If we're training the model with our 6 observations, then the shape of the tensor `x_train` should be `[5,10]` and our `y_train` should be `[5, 2]`.

My question is regarding the construction of the `y_train` tensor. We normally receive the data as an array of dimension `len(n_observations)` where each value corresponds to the different label/class. In order to construct the `y_train` tensor I normally juggle around with `np.zeros` and `np.ones` and `np.stack`.

So in the example described above, if:

```
y_train_raw = np.repeat((1,2,3), 2) #initial format of the training labels
```

I would do something like:

```
label1=np.vstack((np.ones((2,1)), np.zeros((4,1))))
label2 = np.vstack((np.zeros((2,1)),np.ones((2,1)), np.zeros((2,1))))
label3=np.vstack((np.zeros((4,1)), np.ones((2,1))))
y_train = np.column_stack((label1, label2, label3))
```

My question is: is there a way to programmatically make this step faster?

Comment: What about `np.eye(3)[y_train_raw - 1]`? Is it what you want?

Comment: @V.Ayrat yes!!! Thank you!